# sbt unresolved transitive dependencies

Tags: sbt

I cannot seem to configure SBT properly to resolve transitive dependencies from a RootProject my project depends on. The problem seems to be resolvers. I've been able to replicate it with a very simple structure. See below for code.

Inside common/ I can run `sbt console` and it will resolve the dependency and I can use it. However inside proj/ the same command fails. with `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES`. But my `edofic snapshots` resolver isn't listed among tried resolvers. Somehow it isn't picked up. It works if I add the resolver manually to the Build.scala but this defeats the purpose of transitive dependency.

```
├── common
│   └── build.sbt
└── proj
    └── project
        └── Build.scala
```

*common/build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

resolvers += "edofic snapshots" at "http://edofic.github.com/repository/snapshots"

libraryDependencies += "com.edofic" % "reactivemacros_2.10.0" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

*proj/project/Build.scala*

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BarBuild extends Build {
  val common = RootProject(file("../common"))

  val main = Project(id = "main", base = file(".")).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
  ) dependsOn common
}
```

Just to make things clear: I want to have separate SBT configuration for "common" and I don't want to publish it locally-I want to have SBT handle incremental recompilation when needed. Is RootProject the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that worked for me but it's possible it may break something else:
Inside *proj/project/Build.scala* add a "delegates" argument to your Project definition like this:

```
val main = Project(id = "main", base = file("."), 
                   delegates = common :: Nil).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
) dependsOn common
```

I think this may cause your "main" project to pick up all the configuration from the "common" project, so I'm not sure what side effects that may have.  Due to this, the solution I've chosen for my project is to have a "config" project that has common configuration for all my projects and use "delegates" with that project so I can control what configuration is being picked up.